# Use 3 pseudo elements together?

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I want to ask if it is possible to use the pseudo elements `:hover`,  `:not()`, and `:after` together on the same CSS rule

I need to use all 3 for this piece of code:

```
#sidebar ul:not(.sub-menu) li:hover:after{
    content: "";
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Since I have a sidebar where I am using pseudo elements to cause the hover effect on the menu items, but I want to avoid the main menu `<li>`s to get in hover state when a sub menu `<li>` is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You can select it with an easy way like:

```
#sidebar ul li { // Styles for the main li }
```

Then something like this for the sub `<li>` of them :

```
#sidebar ul li > ul li { // Styles for the sub menu li }
```